# trying to limit the user to only entering a prime number

Tags: java, validation

im creating an application that encodes and decodes messages.  Im using RSA cryptography so i need to work with prime numbers.  Ive figured out how to tell if the numbers are prime or not with a method

```
public int checkPrime(int number)
    {
        //Is this number greater than 0
            for(int i = number-1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if((number % i) == 0) 
                {
                        if(i == 1)
                        {
                            System.out.println("is a prime");
                        isPrime = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("is not a prime");
                        isPrime = false;
                        }
                        break;
                }  
             }
             return number;
    }
```

So this prints out if its prime or not.
But what i want to do is to keep asking the user for a number if it is not prime.
I ask the user to enter the input in a class called MenuMethods and then its response is set to variables which then create an instance of the Encrypt class.

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:        userInput
//  Description: This method is used in the MainApp to give the user capability to enter
//               the details when adding details of an employee into the store.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static Encrypt userInput() 
    {
        //String temp = keyboard.nextLine();
        Encrypt encrypt = new Encrypt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the Public Key: ");
        int publicKey = keyboard.nextInt();
        encrypt.checkPrime(publicKey);
        System.out.println("Please enter the Private Key: ");
        int privateKey = keyboard.nextInt();
        encrypt.checkPrime(privateKey);
        return encrypt = new Encrypt(publicKey,privateKey);
    }
```

Can someone please help me with this....

Comment: My problem is the questions are in the MenuMethods class and im confused about how to validate it to only let the user enter a prime :(

Comment: Usually, the prime factory for RSA encryption are generated randomly. Why do you want the user to enter them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wanna do is use a `while` loop:

```
while(!checkPrime(input)) {       
    System.out.println("Please enter a prime number: ");
    input = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

And change the return value of your `checkPrime` to boolean.

Also for checking primes it is sufficient if you check if your number `n` is dividable by a number between 2 and sqrt(n).

Comment: Got it working with your implementation.  Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Make your checkPrime method have a boolean return type, that returns true if prime and false if not, like this:

```
public boolean checkPrime(int n)
{
    boolean ret = true;
    for(int i = 2; i<=((int)Math.sqrt(n));i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            ret = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Then use a while loop similar to this one:

```
int n = 4; //or any non-prime value
while(!checkPrime(n))
{
    n = /*input*/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int number;
do{
   System.out.print("give a prime number:");
   numnber=getNumber();
}while(!checkPrime(number));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You only have to check the i up to c = Math.sqrt(number)
2. Number is prime if for every i (from 2 to c) is true that: number % i != 0

The following code checks if the number is prime:

```
boolean isPrime = false;
for (int i = 2; i <= c; i++)
{
    if (number % i != 0) 
    {
         isPrime = false;
         break;
    }    
}
```